# Extracting all words starting with a certain character

Tags: python

I have a list of lists, in which I store sentences as strings. What I want to do is to get only the words starting with @. In order to do that, I split the sentences into words and now trying to pick only the words that start with @ and exclude all the other words.

```
# to create the empty list:
lst = []

# to iterate through the columns:
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    lst.append(df['col1'][i].split())
```

Comment: "I have a list of lists"
Do you mean a list of strings?

Comment: Share some examples and your works

Comment: No, I mean a list of lists. In each sublist, there was only one sentence. Then I split that sentences into words. So now I again have a list of lists. Each element in the sublist is one word of that sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am mistaken you just need *flat* list containing all words starting with particular character. For doing that I would employ list flattening (via `itertools`):

```
import itertools
first = 'f' #look for words starting with f letter
nested_list = [['This is first sentence'],['This is following sentence']]
flat_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(nested_list))
nested_words = [i.split(' ') for i in flat_list]
words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(nested_words))
lst = [i for i in words if i[0]==first]
print(lst) #output: ['first', 'following']
```